# Materialize CSS - How to make a column have full height?

Tags: html, css, materialize

This is my code, I've started making a simple menu but the problem is that it is not 100% height. I've tried many solutions I have seen on similar posts but none of them help. I have tried setting the min-height, changing between % and vh, and much more but none of it worked.

```js
M.AutoInit()

let sideMenu=document.getElementById("sideMenu")

sideMenu.addEventListener("mouseenter",()=>{
    sideMenu.setAttribute("class", "col s12 m12 l12 side-menu")
})

sideMenu.addEventListener("mouseleave",()=>{
    sideMenu.setAttribute("class", "col s2 m2 l2 side-menu")
})
```

```css
.side-menu{
    background-color: #b9ffc8;
    height: 100% !important;
    transition:ease-in-out .3s;
}

.side-menu:hover{
    background-color: #5eff81;
}

.side-menu-wrapper{
    height: 100% !important;
}

.row {
    height: 100vh !important;
}

.menu-icon{
    color:darkgrey;
    transition: ease-in-out .3s;
}

.side-menu:hover .menu-icon{
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s3 m2 l2 side-menu-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s2 m2 l2 side-menu" id="sideMenu">
                    <i class="small material-icons menu-icon">dehaze</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I answered your question below but if you check out Chrome Dev Tools https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools, you'll quickly be able to spot these things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0;` to the `.row` class. To be more precise add `margin-bottom: 0;`.

You can also remove all the `!important`'s from the `height`'s.

```
.side-menu {
  background-color: #b9ffc8;
  height: 100%;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.side-menu:hover {
  background-color: #5eff81;
}

.side-menu-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.menu-icon {
  color: darkgrey;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.side-menu:hover .menu-icon {
  color: white;
}
```

See it in action on codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNWLVLg

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are talking about the little gap at the bottom.

Row is a Materialize class:

```
.row {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

So if you change your row class to:

```
.row {
  height: 100vh !important;
  margin-bottom:0px !important
}
```

It will override the materialise `margin-bottom:20px` .

And you'll get 100% height